# Verifying strings Java

Tags: java, string

```
do {
            grade[y] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "For student #" + inputGrades.students + " enter grade for course #" + classes);
            if (!grade[y].equals("A") || !grade[y].equals("B") || !grade[y].equals("C") || !grade[y].equals("D") || !grade[y].equals("F")) {
                grade[y] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "For student #" + inputGrades.students + " enter grade for course #" + classes);
            } else {
                validgrade = true;
            }
        } while (!validgrade);
```

I'm trying to make a sure a sting equals either A, B, C, D, or F. I get stuck in an infinite loop. Why?

Comment: Your logic is wrong. Use && not ||. As you put it is never false. If you enter e.g. A it will not be B and therefor your expression is true when it should be false.

Comment: Change your check to `if (!grade[y].matches("[ABCDF]"))` to avoid problems with `||` and `&&`.

Answer (score 5):

This condition is always true:

```
if (!grade[y].equals("A") || !grade[y].equals("B") || !grade[y].equals("C") || !grade[y].equals("D") || !grade[y].equals("F"))
```

`grade[y]` cannot equal `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, and `F` at the same time. At most one `!equals(...)` will be `false`. The remaining four would be `true`, turning the results of `OR` into `true` as well.

You need `&&` instead of `||`:

```
if (!grade[y].equals("A") && !grade[y].equals("B") && !grade[y].equals("C") && !grade[y].equals("D") && !grade[y].equals("F"))
```

In addition, it is not necessary to call `JOptionPane.showInputDialog` inside the `if` conditional. All you need to do is letting the loop continue. So the simplified code could look like this:

```
do {
    grade[y] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "For student #" + inputGrades.students + " enter grade for course #" + classes);
} while (!grade[y].equals("A") && !grade[y].equals("B") && !grade[y].equals("C") && !grade[y].equals("D") && !grade[y].equals("F"));
```